# 'Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token' with legit React code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

[image: The error I'm getting]

I am getting an error when I try to compile my React app. It looks like Babel hasn't been properly configured to transform React code into vanilla JS. I tried many different things, all of them didn't worked. Here's my final code, what I think should be working:

Here's my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      sidebarOpen: false
    }

    this.onSetSidebarOpen = this.onSetSidebarOpen.bind(this);
  }

  onSetSidebarOpen: function(open) {
    this.setState({sidebarOpen: open});
  }

  render: function() {
    var sidebarContent = <b>Sidebar content</b>;

    return (
      <Sidebar sidebar={sidebarContent}
               open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
               onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}>
        <b>Main content</b>
      </Sidebar>
    );
  }
};
```

and here's my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }],
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

and here's my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/, 
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] 
      },
  { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" },
  { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    hot: true
  }
};
```

Don't understand what's missing. Thanks

Comment: Should be `onSetSidebarOpen() { ...etc... }` Check out how classes work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: You are declaring function inside `class`, not inside `object`. You can directly write `onSetSidebarOpen(open) {`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be adding an instance field/member. Use assignment:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  onSetSidebarOpen = function(open) {
    this.setState({sidebarOpen: open});
  };

  ...

}
```

If you initialize in this way, you can skip binding 'this' in the constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    onSetSidebarOpen(open) { this.setState({sidebarOpen: open}) }

    ...

}
```